# Define Enum as a Struct (why use this syntax)

Tags: struct, rust, enums

In Rust's [chrono library](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono) there is this code in [src/format/mod.rs#L338-L345](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/main/src/format/mod.rs#L338-L345):

```rust
pub struct ParseError(ParseErrorKind);

enum ParseErrorKind {
    OutOfRange,
    ...
}
```

1. In the first line, what does the syntax `struct ParseError(ParseErrorKind)` mean? Is enum `ParseErrorKind` somewhat "aliased" as a struct called `ParseError`, or is `ParseError` a struct that contains an anonymous field of enum type `ParseErrorKind`? If the latter, how would one access the field? Or is this something else?
2. What is the advantage of using this `struct` syntax? Why not use `ParseErrorKind` as a type directly (instead of wrapping it into a struct)?

Comment: it's more a historical reason that before we didn't have `#[non_exhaustive]`. there is still some valid usecase but I would not count this one as one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the first line, what does the syntax struct ParseError(ParseErrorKind) mean? Is enum ParseErrorKind somewhat "aliased" as a struct called ParseError, or is ParseError a struct that contains an anonymous field of enum type ParseErrorKind? If the latter, how would one access the field? Or is this something else?

It is a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs), which in this case wraps an inner error type.
The main difference from other structs is that fields are not named. Instead they are accessed like tuples (ex `my_instace.0`, to refer to the inner data).
Refer to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs) for more info

> What is the advantage of using this struct syntax? Why not use ParseErrorKind as a type directly (instead of wrapping it into a struct)?

In this case it abstract the enum constructors over a single type. My guess is that they decided that the error **kind** is an implementation detail and should not be exposed in the API. Notice that `ParseErrorKind` is private while `ParseError` is public (with private access to the single tuple inside).

Additionally, it is also a common pattern to wrap types in order to expand what those types can do if those types are not native to your own crate.